# Can I use Google Drive folder to build sites and web apps from?

Tags: google-drive-api

(MacOS)

I just recently upgraded my Drive storage and downloaded Backup and Sync. I would love to be able to drop my dev directory housing all of my projects into Drive, keep it synced to my computer from Google Drive, and build projects from that folder.

Would this present any downfalls, such as slower builds while syncing, extra RAM usage, unforeseen bugs, etc.? I've researched a little bit, but can't really find many people who've described a workspace as such.

Here's an example path to a project directory I would be building from within my Drive folder: `/Users/user/Google-Drive/sites/site`

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @DaImTo The question pertains mainly to my build process, which is usually a combination of gulp and Docker containers and/or Vue SPA builds, and how the build-speed/memory allocation is affected by building out of the Google Drive folder. That seems directly related to programming tools and processes, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This has long been a deprecated feature since 2015.

> [Deprecating web hosting support in Google
>   Drive](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html):
>
> Beginning August 31, 2015, web hosting in Google Drive for users and
>   developers will be deprecated. Google Apps customers can continue to
>   use this feature for a period of one year until August 31, 2016, when
>   serving content via googledrive.com/host/doc id will be discontinued.
>
> In the time since web hosting in Drive was launched, a wide variety of
>   public web content hosting services have emerged, and we think better
>   options are available to people today. As a result, we have decided to
>   discontinue this feature and focus on the core Drive and Google Apps
>   experience.

Stick to formal ways of hosting sites and web apps. You can try [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) or [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) if it serves you.

Comment: I'm not trying to use Drive hosting, I'm trying to use Drive for storage on my machine/the cloud and building out of that directory locally. For example, I have a large website directory stored within the Google Drive folder that's synced to my root directory. If I fire up a Docker container and build this project that's inside the Google Drive folder being synced (to edit locally), will that have any negative affects in terms of speed or memory as compared to doing the same process with the directory just placed in my root folder and not inside the Drive folder that's being synced.